# android sqlite and ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Tutorial for SQLite and ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685027/good-tutorial-for-sqlite-and-listview)

Is there an example on how to use `ListView` with `sqlite` to read all rows in table  at once 
or what do i change in the cursor to make it read all the titles at once

```
   //---get all titles---
   db.open();
   Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
   String text = "";
   if (c.moveToFirst())
   {
      do {          
          DisplayTitle(c, text);
      } while (c.moveToNext());
   }
   db.close();
}

public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c, String text)
{
     ListView.setText("id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" + 
         "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" + 
         "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + 
         "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3));
} 

//---retrieves all the titles---
public Cursor getAllTitles() 
{
   return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID, 
            KEY_ISBN,
            KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_PUBLISHER}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to show titles in a listview from sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Use any subclass of [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), like

```
       Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
       SimpleCursorAdapter a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(c, ....);
       listview.setAdapter(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you can't read all rows in sqlite and put them all at once in listview if you mean that. you must read each row in sqlite and put it in listview with adapter. i mostly use SimpleAdapter.

you can see example [HERE](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/)

edit part of code to read from base:

```
 // prepare the list of all records
    String[] columns={"id", "nick", "pass"}; 
    Cursor result=sampleDB.query("table", columns, "", null, null, null, null);
    result.moveToPosition(0); 
    while (!result.isAfterLast()) { 
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("rowid", result.getString(0));
        map.put("col_1", result.getString(1));
        map.put("col_2", result.getString(2));
        fillMaps.add(map);
        result.moveToNext();
    }
```